# Eclipse error during resolving gradle dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, dependencies

I have added the dependency `com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.4` to `build.gradle`, but Eclipse doesn't resolve this dependency and throws this error

```
Illegal entry in Gradle Dependencies: D:/Programs/Eclipse/unresolved dependency - com.sun.mail javax.mail 1.5.4 PluginName      Unknown org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.classpathcontainer
```

I tried to clean & rebuild the project, refresh dependencies many times, but I still get the same error and the dependency doesn't download. What can be wrong?

My `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'PluginName',
               'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name 'Sponge maven repo'
        url 'http://repo.spongepowered.org/maven'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.spongepowered:spongeapi:2.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.4'
}

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'repos'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definietly don't know why, but It started to work and dependency just downloaded.